# Android intents and services

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I'm having a requirement of designing an update service for the application, this update service will pull the data from the clued and it should update the GUI if there is new updates. The first part is straight forward but for the second part what is the best approach?

I'm thinking of having a custom intent receiver which will be registered in the application and it will tell the activities to load the content again. Moreover if the application closed I need to show a custom dialog from activity telling about updates.

I need your feedbacks and if any body is having similar sample project please share it to look at the implementation details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to sync your data to a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and when your activity starts, register to observe changes of that provider through

```
ContentResolver.registerContentObserver()
```

As I remember the jumpnote app uses this. [link](http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/source/checkout)